# php check if an instance variable is declared but not assigned

Tags: php

What is a good way to check if an instance variable has never been assigned. Consider the following example. `$this->foo` is null to start. If `$this->foo` is found in the database, subsequent calls to `getFoo()` won't query the database. However, if there is nothing in the database that gets returned(null) all subsequent calls still hit the database..not good.

```
class FooBar 
{    
  protected $foo;
  protected $db;    

  public function getFoo()
  {
    if (is_null($this->foo)) {
      $this->foo = $this->db->getFooFromDatabase();
    }

    return $this->foo;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to use a dummy value instead of null...that way you can differentiate between 'not set' and 'null'.

Comment: @Mark i think you're right. Didn't know if there's a popular value/object/constant way of doing this

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a hack, I guess, but how about simply not setting it? Then simply check whether the object has that property.

```
class FooBar 
{   
  //REMOVED
  //protected $foo;
  protected $db;    

  public function getFoo()
  {
    if (! property_exists($this, 'foo')) {
      $this->foo = $this->db->getFooFromDatabase();
    }

    return $this->foo;
  }
}
```

Comment: `isset` also checks if it's null..I don't think this will work.

Comment: You're right, and I believe `property_exists` is meant for that. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that short of keeping a separate "assigned thus far" boolean flag. In most cases the default value (as in this case, usually `null`) serves adequately as a sentinel, and I don't see why it would not be able to serve also in this example. You could have either your query method return `false` on not finding a foo, or you could leave it as is and use `false` as the initial value of the property.

I would suggest the first approach: returning `null` after querying the database doesn't make sense most of the time, the usual semantics of `null` being "not known". Since the database was just queried the code *does* know, even if the knowledge is "nothing's there".

Comment: I think he's saying that `foo` might be set in the DB, but it's set to `null`. He can't differentiate between "not set" and "foo is null" because foo is null by default.

Comment: @Mark: Then it could be done the other way, using some other constant value as a placeholder. That could be `false`, and it could be semantically reinforced with `const UNKNOWN = false` and `protected $foo = self::UNKNOWN`.

Comment: I wouldn't use `false` as the unknown either; I'd create a whole dummy singleton class so that it has its own type. I think ASP.NET MVC does with with their `DbNull` class.

Comment: @Mark: There's no need, if you are OK with using an object you can use *any* object at all (e.g. `new stdClass`). Comparing objects with `===` has reference equality semantics, so you will always be able to tell the sentinel apart. I have used this technique to good effect, but only when I absolutely had to. It's unwieldy (must set initial value inside the constructor).

Comment: I suppose you could use `stdClass` as your sentinel value, but then where would you store it? In a global variable? I'd prefer a getter on a static method (since PHP doesn't have static readonly values). Anyway, you're right, this might be overengineering; I like SolarBear's solution as it's simple, clear, and looks like it should work.